# Filter JSON File to fetch only required data

Tags: ajax, json

Is is possible to fetch only a subset of data within a JSON file with ajax ? Does the filtering need to be done after fetching all data? I want to get for example, products with a price in the range of $100-$500. Can this be done without having to get all products and then filter the results ?

Answer (score 1):

- General answer is NO, you can't filter products before fetching them all
- If your json provider supports filtering - then you may use some special query to get only a subset of products

Comment: Thanks for clearing that out. I thought so since I found no examples for doing this. I guess filtering after fetching it is then. Cheers